# Pandas agg fuction with operations on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, multiple-columns

I am interested if we can use pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg function to make arithmetic operations on multiple columns columns. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(15).reshape(5, 3))
df['C'] = [0, 0, 2, 2, 5]
print(df.groupby('C').mean()[0] - df.groupby('C').mean()[1])
print(df.groupby('C').agg({0: 'mean', 1: 'sum', 2: 'nunique', 'C': 'mean0-mean1'}))
```

Is it somehow possible that we receive result like in this example: the difference between means of column 0 and column 1 grouped by column 'C'?
df

```
    0   1   2  C
0   0   1   2  0
1   3   4   5  0
2   6   7   8  2
3   9  10  11  2
4  12  13  14  5
```

Groupped difference

```
C
0   -1.0
2   -1.0
5   -1.0
dtype: float64
```

I am not interested with solutions that does not use agg method. I am curious only if agg method can take multiple columns as argument and then do some operations on them to return one columns after job is done.

Comment: Maybe `agg` is not meant for that

Comment: what is your desired data set?

Comment: I just want to be able to get arithmetic operations on multiple columns using agg.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
In [12]: df.groupby('C').mean().diff(axis=1)
Out[12]:
    0    1    2
C
0 NaN  1.0  1.0
2 NaN  1.0  1.0
5 NaN  1.0  1.0
```

or

```
In [13]: df.groupby('C').mean().diff(-1, axis=1)
Out[13]:
     0    1   2
C
0 -1.0 -1.0 NaN
2 -1.0 -1.0 NaN
5 -1.0 -1.0 NaN
```